# Validar si filas vienen vacias e insertar - laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

estoy hace un par de días pegado en un tema que no se como podría resolver: tengo una tabla que de forma dinámica puedo agregarle o quitarle filas, dentro de estas filas hay campos que se deben llenar para insertar en la base de datos, tengo  escenarios:
1.- cuando escribo algún registro inserta sin problemas (resuelto)
2.- debo hacer que cuando no se escribió nada ( o sea no se agregaron filas) se haga el otro insert de forma normal (acá estoy fallando), entiendo debo hacer alguna validación para comprobar que si hay registros en la tabla inserte, y si no solo haga el primer insert de la tabla

En la vista tengo una tabla asi, la cual va almacenando en arreglos los campos de las filas que se van insertando:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicAddRemove">
                        <tr>
                            <th>NOMBRES</th>
                            <th>APELLIDO PATERNO</th>
                            <th>APELLIDO MATERNO</th>
                            <th>RUT</th>
                            <th>TELÉFONO</th>
                            <th>CORREO ELECTRONICO</th>
                            <th>OPCIONES</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][nombres_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Nombre(s)" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][ape_pat_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Apellido Paterno" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][ape_mat_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Apellido Materno" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][rut_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Rut/Documento" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][telefono_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Teléfono" class="form-control @error('telefono_asistente') is-invalid @enderror" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][email_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Email" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="dynamic-ar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Añadir</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

el js de la vista (que va generando o eliminando las filas de la tabla de forma dinamica:

```
 var i = 0;
    $("#dynamic-ar").click(function () {
        ++i;
        $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[' + i +'][nombres_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Nombre(s)" class="form-control" /></td> <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[' + i +'][ape_pat_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Apellido Paterno" class="form-control" /></td> <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[' + i +'][ape_mat_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Apellido Materno" class="form-control" /></td> <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[' + i +'][rut_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Rut/Documento" class="form-control" /></td> <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[' + i +'][telefono_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Teléfono" class="form-control" /></td> <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[' + i +'][email_asistente]" placeholder="Escriba Email" class="form-control" /></td> <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-input-field">Quitar</button></td></tr>'
            );
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-input-field', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
```

y finalmente en el controlador la funcion que estoy tratando de usar:

```
  $solicitud = new solicitudAcceso();
    $solicitud->nombres = $request->get('nombres');
    $solicitud->ape_pat = $request->get('ape_pat');
    $solicitud->ape_mat = $request->get('ape_mat');
    $solicitud->rut = $request->get('rut');
    $solicitud->institucion = $request->get('institucion');
    $solicitud->cargo = $request->get('cargo');
    $solicitud->unidad = strtoupper($request->get('unidad'));
    $solicitud->jornada = $request->get('jornada');
    $solicitud->telefono = $request->get('telefono');
    $solicitud->email = $request->get('email');
    $solicitud->motivo_visita = $request->get('motivo_visita');
    $solicitud->fecha_realizacion_visita = $request->get('fecha_realizacion_visita');
    $solicitud->hora_ingreso = $request->get('hora_ingreso');
    $solicitud->hora_salida = $request->get('hora_salida');
    $solicitud->movilizacion = $request->get('movilizacion');
    $solicitud->fecha_movilizacion = $request->get('fecha_movilizacion');
    $solicitud->status = 0;
    $solicitud->save();

    //Contamos si hay mas de una fila en la tabla asistentes
    $asistentes []= $request->input('addMoreInputFields');
    $cantidad = count($asistentes);

    if(isset($asistentes)&&count($asistentes)){
        foreach($asistentes as $key => $value) {
            asistentes::create([
                'nombres'=>$value['nombres_asistente'],
                'ape_pat' => $value['ape_pat_asistente'],
                'ape_mat' => $value['ape_mat_asistente'],
                'rut' => $value['rut_asistente'],
                'telefono' => $value['telefono_asistente'],
                'email' => $value['email_asistente'],
                'solicitud_acceso_id' => $solicitud->id
            ]);
        }
```

al intentar registrar sin ingresar un asistente (en la tabla dinamica) me arroja error:

Undefined index: nombres_asistente (linea que esta dentro del if)

Comment: Que es lo que está fallando? Podrias incluir en la pregunta un ejemplo de cada posibilidad de request y qué es lo que quieres hacer con cada uno?

Comment: añadi ejemplo del error, lo que busco es que se haga el primer insert, y comprobar si hay algo escrito en la primer fila de la tabla, en caso contrario que se salte el insert en esta segunda tabla, en caso de que haya algo escrito en esta fila insertar en la segunda tabla

Comment: Lo del error probablemente porque haces `$asistentes []= $request->input('addMoreInputFields');` en lugar de `$asistentes = $request->input('addMoreInputFields') ?? [];`, ya que el campo `addMoreInputFields` ya sería un array o `null`. Para validar, [hay reglas](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input) que ya trae laravel, sólo deberías aplicarlas

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `$value['nombres_asistente']` no existe, antes de ir a por insertar cosas a la base de datos debes validar que si se está recibiendo y que no se está recibiendo del formulario/request o de la base de datos.

Aquí es donde entran los controles internos basados en campos, algo como esto debería solucionar el error (ojo yo uso operaciones ternarias para la validación):

```
// Obtener los asistentes de la solicitud
$asistentes = $request->input('addMoreInputFields');

// Crear la solicitud principal
$solicitud = new solicitudAcceso();
// Asignar los valores de la solicitud principal

// Guardar la solicitud principal
$solicitud->save();

// Verificar si hay asistentes ingresados
if(isset($asistentes) && count($asistentes)){
    foreach($asistentes as $key => $value) {
        // Verificar si los campos existen antes de acceder a ellos
        $nombres = isset($value['nombres_asistente']) ? $value['nombres_asistente'] : '';
        $ape_pat = isset($value['ape_pat_asistente']) ? $value['ape_pat_asistente'] : '';
        $ape_mat = isset($value['ape_mat_asistente']) ? $value['ape_mat_asistente'] : '';
        $rut = isset($value['rut_asistente']) ? $value['rut_asistente'] : '';
        $telefono = isset($value['telefono_asistente']) ? $value['telefono_asistente'] : '';
        $email = isset($value['email_asistente']) ? $value['email_asistente'] : '';

        // Crear el asistente
        asistentes::create([
            'nombres' => $nombres,
            'ape_pat' => $ape_pat,
            'ape_mat' => $ape_mat,
            'rut' => $rut,
            'telefono' => $telefono,
            'email' => $email,
            'solicitud_acceso_id' => $solicitud->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

La segunda pregunta que hiciste sobre saltarte el insert no está relacionado al error que colocaste en tu post, también tendrías que hacer validaciones ya que no es recomendable meter cosas vacías a la bases de datos.